# Azure-ML-R SDK in R Studio ScriptRunConfig not recognized function error after a deprecated estimator replacement

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to use Azure-ML-SDK in R Studio and used Estimator but got error stating estimator deprecated and advised to use ScriptRunConfig and when used it, it not being recognized as a function and fails to run. See the errors below. Please advise.

Already loaded library(azuremlsdk) which should include azureml.core to recognize the ScriptRunConfig function. Is it version compatibility issue? if so, which version should i use for ScriptRunConfig and how to load specific R version in Azure ML Compute (R Studio web interface and not R Studio Desktop)

First Error and code

```
est <- estimator(source_directory = "train-and-deploy-first-model",
                 entry_script = "accidents.R",
                 script_params = list("--data_folder" = ds$path(target_path)),
                 compute_target = compute_target
                 )
```

cran_packages, github_packages, custom_url_packages, custom_docker_image, image_registry_details, use_gpu, environment_variables, and shm_size parameters will be deprecated. Please create an environment object with them using r_environment() and pass the environment object to the estimator().'enabled' is deprecated. Please use the azureml.core.runconfig.DockerConfiguration object with the 'use_docker' param instead.
'Estimator' is deprecated. Please use 'ScriptRunConfig' from 'azureml.core.script_run_config' with your own defined environment or an Azure ML curated environment.

Second Code snippet trying to fix above and it's error

```
config <- ScriptRunConfig(source_directory = ".",
                 script = "accidents.R",
                 compute_target = compute_target
                 )
```

Error in ScriptRunConfig(source_directory = ".", script = "accidents.R",  :
could not find function "ScriptRunConfig"

Comment: You first error is not an actual error but a warning that functionality you are using is deprecated (which usually means it will not be supported in future versions so you better port your code to the new API as soon as it suits you). My guess is that the source of your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Hope I could find more info about the error because I tried number of times keeping the code from sample in tact by letting Azure ML web based R studio to determine config and not making any changes to code but the sample itself seems throwing error and unsure if it’s incorrect. Anyway waiting for R SDK general availability with documentation

Comment: I've been working first with Azure support and now one of their product engineers for two weeks now trying to get Azure to work with R. The answer I've received is that you should not use the R SDK since it's depreciated and there aren't any plans to improve on it. They told me the preferred way is to create a Python driver script that does all the Azure SDK stuff and have it call separate .R scripts for Experiments.

When I asked for an end-to-end example of this, they said there wasn't any. After two weeks, I'm still not sure how this is supposed to work.